# MySQL - Select all unique records that do not contain certain values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct, exists

(Sorry if question has been asked before or is too simple)

Select all the unique Names from the table Students where level = 'High school' and don't have sports ('Soccer', 'Basketball') subjects.

```
ID      name    level          subject

00001   John    High school Science
00002   John    High school Math
00003   John    High school *Soccer*
00004   John    High school English
00005   Andrea  High school Math
00006   Andrea  High school Science
00007   Andrea  High school English
00008   Susan   High school History
00009   Susan   High school English
00010   Susan   High school Math
00011   Michael High school Since
00012   Michael High school Math
00013   Michael High school *Basketball*
00014   Michael High school English
00015   Mary    Middle school   Math
```

I tried using 'EXISTS' like this:

```
SELECT ID, name, level FROM Students WHERE level = 'High school' AN NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT * FROM Students WHERE subject IN ('Soccer', 'Basketball') );
```

Result should be:

```
Andrea  High school
Susan   High school
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *correlate* your subquery with the outer query, using the `name` column :

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.name,  s.level
FROM students s
WHERE s.level = 'High school'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM students s1 WHERE s1.name = s.name AND s1.subject IN ('Soccer', 'Basketball')  
)
```

Without correlation, the subquery actually checks if *all* records in `students` have a subject different than `'Soccer'` and `'Basketball'`, which is false, resulting in no results being returned by the outer query.

This **[demo on Db Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ji6sdVzwdG1tYbbxJb1w68/0)** with your sample data yields :

```
| name   | level       |
| ------ | ----------- |
| Andrea | High school |
| Susan  | High school |
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, name, level FROM Students WHERE level = 'High school' AND  subject NOT IN ('Soccer', 'Basketball') ;
```

Comment: this will bring up Micheal, not what he wants.

Comment: He mentioned list all names except subject like soccer and basketball in his requirement.

Comment: Did you see what the result should look like?

Comment: I agree with you.